# Trying to convert Cross-Filter Report to a SOQL query

Tags: soql

I need to convert a cross-filter report of Leads and Activities to a SOQL query.

Filters

- All Leads
- Created Date: All Time

Cross Filters

Leads without Activities

- Subject contains: voicemail, call, etc
- Created Date equals LAST 90 DAYS

This is what I have done so far, I'm struggling to find the logic to only include "Leads without valid activities in the last 90 days":

```
[SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Tasks 
                       WHERE CreatedDate <= :d 
                         AND Subject LIKE :subjects)
            FROM Lead WHERE OwnerId != sfAdmin.Id]
//d = "LAST 90 Days in my code"
//subjects = "List of all the valid subjects"
//sfAdmin.Id = "Id of a specific user"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This query is actually not supported in SOQL, if you want your root query object to remain `Lead`. With other child objects, you could do it via `Left Inner Join`, also known as `semi join inner select`. Here's what it would look like:

```
SELECT ... FROM Lead WHERE Id IN (
    SELECT WhatId FROM Task
    WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_90_DAYS
    AND Subject IN ('Voicemail, 'Call')
)
```

However, trying to run this query will yield an error:

> Entity 'Task' is not supported for semi join inner selects

Your alternatives are to create a rollup that you can use as a filter, or to query the `Task` records as step 1, then use it to filter `Lead` ids in step 2. The latter would look like:

```
Set<Id> leadIds = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([
    SELECT WhatId Id FROM Task
    WHERE What.Type = 'Lead'
    AND CreatedDate = LAST_90_DAYS
    AND Subject IN ('Voicemail', 'Call')
    GROUP BY WhatId
]).keySet();
List<Lead> filteredLeads = [SELECT ... FROM Lead WHERE Id IN :leadIds];
```

If you don't mind switching your primary query object to be `Task`, it may be simpler to do that, and you can do your filtering accordingly.